# How do I make one subproject depend on another subproject in gradle via configurations?

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I have a multi-project build that looks like this:

```
helloworld
- projecta
  - build.gradle
- projectb
  - build.gradle
- build.gradle
```

`projecta` creates some files and `projectb` zips them up. I want `projectb` to depend on `projecta`.

Right now, I simply have a `dependsOn ':projecta:build` in my `projectb`'s build.gradle. But this feels like a hack.

I want to use configurations instead to make it look like this:

```
// projectb build.gradle
dependencies {
  compile project(':projecta')
}
```

But I cannot find any documentation on how to define a compile task. How would I go do this?

Comment: What are projecta and projectb (Native C project/ Java App / Android) and are they both same type of project?

Comment: @Hedge7707 they are both vanilla gradle subprojects. `projecta` just generates a random strings from /dev/urandom and `projectb` does some transformations and bundles it up. I eventually want to make a `projectc` that does different transformations as well so `projecta` needs to be shared functionality.

Answer (score 1):

The philosophy in Gradle is to model exactly what you are aiming for:

- Are the files produced by `projecta` a real output of the project itself, like a JAR in the Java world?

  If yes, then work with a configuration indeed that will give you access to these files, assuming they are properly registered as a production of `projecta`
- Are the files a by product of building `projecta` but not made for general consumption?

  If that's the case, then the most explicit dependency is across tasks where the zipping task in `projectb` simply depends on the task from `projecta` that produces these files. `build` here feels like a hack in the sense that it most likely cause much more work in `projecta` compared to what `projectb` really needs.

Comment: The files in `projecta` are a real output of the subproject. `projecta` generates random strings and puts them into a file. `projectb` and eventually a `projectc` will do some transformations on the files `projecta` generates and then zips them up as well.

I just don't see any tutorials on how to create configurations on vanilla gradle projects/subprojects